# How to scatter columns of a matrix using C and MPI when doing matrix multiplication on NxN matrix

Tags: c, matrix, parallel-processing, mpi, matrix-multiplication

I have a project to write a program that does matrix multiplication on two NxN matrices A and B. I can use any algorithm, but we learned about Cannon's algorithm in class, so that's probably the one I'll use.

I'm having trouble using the scatter function to send each column of B to a processor. I've read through other posts on this, but I'm still not really understanding how to use MPI_Type_vector properly, so I can't figure out what is wrong with my code.

Here is my attempt below, it gives me a segmentation fault:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  int N = 10;
  int i, j;
  int proc_rank, world_size;
  float *A, *B[N];
  float *A_recv, *B_recv[N];
  float *C;
  MPI_Request requests[2];
  MPI_Status stat;

  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &proc_rank);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

      /* MAKE NxN MATRICES A & B */

  A = (float*) malloc(N*N*sizeof(float*));
  A_recv = (float*) malloc(N*sizeof(float*));
  C = (float*) malloc(N*N*sizeof(float*));

  for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
    B[i] = (float *)malloc(N * sizeof(float));
    B_recv[i] = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float));
  }

  if (proc_rank == 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
          *(A + i*N + j) = i*0.2342 + j*0.1231;
          B[i][j] = i*0.5431 + j*0.8934;
      }
    }
  }

      /* CREATE DATA TYPES FOR SCATTER */

  MPI_Datatype acol, acoltype, bcol, bcoltype;

  if (proc_rank == 0) {
    MPI_Type_vector(10, 1, 10, MPI_FLOAT, &acol);
    MPI_Type_commit(&acol);
    MPI_Type_create_resized(acol, 0, 1*sizeof(float), &acoltype);
  }
  MPI_Type_vector(10, 1, 1, MPI_FLOAT, &bcol);
  MPI_Type_commit(&bcol);
  MPI_Type_create_resized(bcol, 0, 1*sizeof(float), &bcoltype);
  MPI_Type_commit(&bcoltype);


      /* SCATTER */

  MPI_Scatter(B, 1, acoltype, B_recv, 1, bcoltype, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  MPI_Scatter(A, N, MPI_FLOAT, A_recv, N, MPI_FLOAT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);


      /* CHECK RESULTS */

  if (proc_rank == 1) {
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      printf("%d %f %f \n", proc_rank, A_recv[i], B_recv[i]);
    }
  }
  if (proc_rank == 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      printf("%d %f %f \n", proc_rank, A[i+10], B[i][1]);
    }
  }

  free(A);
  free(B);
  free(A_recv);
  //free(B_recv);    
  free(C);

  MPI_Finalize();

  return 0;
}
```

I was told it was easiest to format the matrices as arrays, where say elements 0-9 are row 0, elements 10-19 are row 1, etc. which is why A is like that. But then the examples I could find on how to send columns of B seemed to use it as a 2D array, so there's an issue that they don't match and that could make things more challenging later on.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: I didn't look too deep in the code so far, but what's obvious is that you shouldn't use `MPI_Type_resized()` here. The results of your `MPI_Type_vector()` calls seem (at first glance) correct and suitable for your need. Just try to use them directly in your MPI communication calls.

Comment: I see a number of problems. You are not committing the resized type in rank 0. Also, `B_recv` is allocated in a non-contiguous way and is therefore not suitable for use in `MPI_Scatter`. `MPI_Type_vector(10, 1, 1, MPI_FLOAT, &bcol);` could be replaced by `MPI_Type_contiguous(10, MPI_FLOAT, &bcol);` In some of the `malloc` calls you are using `sizeof(float*)` when it should actually be `sizeof(float)`. There might be other problems too.

Comment: Thanks. I tried working with your suggestions, but I'm still having trouble. At best, I could get it to compile and run with no segmentation fault, but many of the values appear as 0.